# Why i get error on build angular 12 application?

Tags: css, sass, angular-cli, angular12

Angular 12.

When i run script

```
ng build
```

I get a lot of errors like

```
Error: styles.62d50503994eb31b6b18.css from Css Minimizer
Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin

name.component.scss from Css Minimizer
Error: [object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with styles optimization, the default settings have changed in v.12
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration

Try to disable the inlineCritical in the optimization options (angular.json):

```
"optimization": {
   "scripts": true,
   "styles": {
      "minify": true,
      "inlineCritical": false
   },
   "fonts": true
},
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. Able to fix it by using following configuration in `angular.json`

`optimization: false,
outputHashing:'all',
sourceMap:true,
vendorChunk:true,
buildOptimizer:false,
namedChunks:true`