# Getting error when try to build docker image in angular

Tags: angular

Hi i am trying to build and docker image using the default angular application. My versions
Angular CLI: 12.2.2
Node: 14.17.5
Package Manager: npm 6.14.14
OS: win32 x64

my Dockerfile code is
FROM node:14.17.5-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#### STAGE 2: Run

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
#COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/test-app /usr/share/nginx/html

but getting below error. Can anyone help me I am new to angular and docker.

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx480.jpg)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWSRS.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx480.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849272/why-i-get-error-on-build-angular-12-application ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.